# Prevent hash signs (#) showing up in Excel without changing cell format or width

Tags: excel, vba, hash, format

I have the following Excel VBA code:

```
Sheet1.Columns.ColumnWidth = 8.14
Sheet1.Rows.EntireRow.RowHeight = Sheet1.Cells(1).Width
Sheet1.Cells.WrapText = True
Sheet1.Cells.NumberFormat = "F0 P0 C0" & vbLf & "00 00 00"
Sheet1.Cells.Value = 123456789
```

The first two lines make the cells in my sheet perfect squares of 8.14 horizontal points and the following lines intend to make each cell look like this (aka displaying a 9 digit number in visually "separated" sections within the same cell):

```
F1 P2 C3
45 67 89
```

The problem is that Excel replaces my number (which should exactly fit into that 8.14 pts sized cell on 2 lines, since it's word-wrapped) with hash signs (#), because of its perceived length - and I don't want that.

Is there a way, through Excel settings or VBA code, to prevent this automated behavior without changing the cell format to 'General' or 'Text' or increasing the cell's width?

Now I've seen this question answered before, but all the answers referred to changing the cell format or size, which I can't do, for a couple of reasons:

- this sheet is intented to be a more or less geographical "map", in which each cell is a point on that map, so naturally I need as many "points" as possible displayed in the visible section in Excel. If I make the cells (squares) larger, I can barely fit a 10x4 grid into the visible section, at 100% zoom - since I must double the cell's previous size to a huge 124 pixels, in order for Excel to display my number unaltered
- if I change the format to 'Text' (aka String cell values), my Excel file becomes huge (cca. 1MB) and virtually unusable, since the map is around 255x128 "points". 255x128 number formatted cells work blisteringly fast compared to the same amount of 'text'/string formatted cells
- if I change the format to 'General' is more or less the same story as above, plus, I can't use custom formats to "separate" my number sections as seen in my example (and yes, this is the intended appearance).

EDIT: While checking http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/forcing-carriage-return-in-custom-date-format/ I found this from a certain Dave (credits to him), which is also the solution to my problem:

*If you try to shrink the columnwidth, you’ll notice you’ll see ####’s way before you (or I) think you should. But a slight change can fix this. On the alignment tab of the format cell dialog, turn off wraptext (if it’s on). Turn on “shrink to fit”, then turn on wraptext.*

I tried it and it worked! The VBA code for this is equally simple - adding the code below right after my initial code did the trick:

```
Sheet1.Cells.WrapText = False
Sheet1.Cells.ShrinkToFit = True
Sheet1.Cells.WrapText = True
```

I didn't want to "cheat" and answer to my own question, so I wrote this as an edit to my original post.

Comment: Excel replaces true numbers with ###### whenever it cannot display the entire true number; this is to avoid 'fooling' the viewer into thinking that there is a number in the cell that is not the actual underlying value. If you want the number to be truncated or to spill into the next cell then use text-that-looks-like-a-number. If you want to avoid some seven digit numbers that don't fit into the same cell that other seven digit numbers do use a non-proportional font.

Comment: @Jeeped Yeah, well, I already explained why I can't use "text-that-looks-like-a-number" - it turns my Excel into a turtle, compared to working with "number-that-looks-like-a-text" solution. I actually had those cells filled with 'text' (aka Strings) data before, but switched because of the speed of working with numbers. I would like to display both alpha- and numeric characters in my cells as a matter of fact, but the 'text' format leads to huge speed problems, as explained above.

Comment: Well, sometimes the answer to a question is simply *'You cannot do that without compromise. Not now; not ever.'* The hashmarks are there for a valid reason; if you are not willing to change the cell formatting or convert the  numbers to text there is simply no way to accomplish what you are attempting. This is behavior by design.

Comment: Well, the design should take the WordWrap setting (which is set to True) in consideration as well - not only for text, but for numbers as well. I agree with you that the hashmarks are there for a reason, however that reason would have been truly valid if the Word Wrap was disabled. Just saying...

Comment: @Jeeped I've just updated my post, check it out. It turns out **it is possible** ... _both now and ever_. I've just tested in VBA code as well and it works. Thank you for your help, but I have to say, I'm one of those people who really hate the "it can't be done" type of answers.

Comment: You are changing the font size and/or kerning the font spacing. That would be formatting the cell.

Comment: @Jeeped Edited my original question again, this time posting the tiny VBA code required as well. Yeah, essentially, it is formatting the cell, however what I meant was more like "without changing the 'type' to 'Text'" kind of format. I will concede, maybe I should have been more clear when asking the question. I think it's understandable (and forgivable) for my first post here on StackOverflow.

Comment: fwiw, you might also find the U2002 to U200B unicode characters (hair space, thin space, en space, three-per-em space) useful as replacements to a regular space character in the format mask. Use the CharMap utility for these. Arial Narrow as a font choice is another option as it significantly reduces the lateral picas (...?) of a string.

Comment: @Jeeped Yep, that's in my sight - thanks.