# How to shrink column width with multiple-line custom number formats?

Tags: excel, vba, format, number-formatting, multiline

I discovered a trick, but Excel doesn't want to cooperate fully... but maybe there's a workaround...?

I often end up with a date/time on a "tall row" (since other columns are multi-line):

[image: img 1-line]

...and I'd like to save vertical space by splitting the date/time onto **2 lines**, while keeping it a *single numeric value* for reasons of sorting, etc:

[image: img 2-line]

---

I realized that this can be accomplished by using a `␊LineFeed` character in the [custom number format](https://support.office.com/article/create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4), one of two ways:

***Method #1:* On a keyboard with a numeric keypad:**

1. Select the cell with the value.
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to open the [**Number Formats** dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E40mh.png).
3. Choose the `Custom` category and then in the `Type:` textbox:

   - Enter the first part of your [custom format](https://support.office.com/article/create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4), ie. `yyyy-mm-dd`
   - While holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> enter `0010` on the [numeric keypad](https://support.office.com/article/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0), and then release <kbd>Alt</kbd>
   - Enter the second part of your custom format, ie. `HH:mm am/pm`
4. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Drag between the row headers to make the row twice as tall:
   [image: imgdrag]
6. If `Wrap Text` is not already on, click it on the **Home** tab of the ribbon: [image: imgWordWrap]

---

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + `0010` enters a `␊LineFeed` character.

> **Note:** Since Excel doesn't expect this character, the *first line* you enter in the `Type` box will disappear as soon as you enter the `␊LineFeed` character.  There's no way to see it within the dialog (without deleting the `␊LineFeed`), but it's still there.

---

***Method #2:* On a keyboard without a numeric keypad and/or using VBA:**

In the VBA Editor, either within your procedure, or in the *Immediate Window* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>), you can set the [number format](https://support.office.com/article/create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4) for `A1` with something like:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat="yyyy-mm-dd" & vbLf &  "HH:mm am/pm"
```

...then adjust the [row height](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-rowheight-property-excel) and make sure [`Wrap Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-wraptext-property-excel) is on, via VBA or with steps #5 & 6 above.

`vbLf` (or `Chr(10)`) represents a `␊LineFeed` character in VBA.

---

## My issue:

This is cool, but it seems that **Excel still treats the value like it's *one long string on a single line***.

**This is demonstrated by:**

- double-clicking between column headers to **[AutoFit](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/resize-a-table-column-or-row-9340d478-21be-4392-81cf-488f7bbd6715)** the column:
  *The column does not "shrink" any further.*
- double-clicking between row headers to **AutoFit** the rows:
  *The row does not "grow to double height".*
- manually dragging the column to a narrower size.
  *Excel "thinks" the value doesn't fit:*

  [image: Img ###### Error]         [image: img]

---

> ### **Any ideas for a workaround?**
>
> Perhaps there's a hack to force Excel to display partial values instead of `######` when a formatted numeric value doesn't fit?

*Thanks!*

Comment: fwiw, for those with notebooks or tablets with no numpad, ctrl+J works as a linefeed in both custom number formats and the Find textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to shrink-wrap it. See the OP's edit here:

[Prevent hash signs (#) showing up in Excel without changing cell format or width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257740/prevent-hash-signs-showing-up-in-excel-without-changing-cell-format-or-width)

1. Go to the Alignment tab in the Format Cells dialogue.
2. Select "Shrink to fit".
3. Select "Wrap text".
4. Click "OK".

[image]

Excel will still auto-size the column to ~139 pixels, but you can drag the column width to ~71 pixels and still see both lines.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Shrink to fit function is ticked

Go to: Right click on cell --> Format Cells --> Alignment --> Shrink to fit

[image: Right click on cell]

[image: Click Shrink to Fit]

Comment: When `Wrap Text` is checked, `Shrink to Fit` is disabled.  You can't have multiple lines *and* use `Shrink to Fit`.

Comment: First you need to check `Shrink to fit` and then check `Wrap text` since when you check `Wrap text` first `Shrink to Fit` becomes disabled

Answer (score 0):

For this example, you can split on two cells instead of doing that. On the first cell, just put the date format without time. On the second cell, do a formula `=(the first cell)`, but put it in time format.

I am looking at a way to shrink this to fit on multiple lines in a cell, but it looks like we don't have the technology to do that automatically in 2020.